# How to query the notion database in the same drag and drop order as on the Notion UI?

Tags: notion-api

I am currently having problems querying data in the database's drag and drop order. I tried reading through notion's database queries, and looking for solutions online. But still there is no way.
I want to querying data in the database's drag and drop order.